# Tensorflow does not recognize GPU on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow

So here it goes: I wanted to use TensorFlow with GPU on AWS - p2.xlarge plan. Unfortunately, something must have gone wrong and I continue to get:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device to node 'Variable_1': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no devices matching that specification are registered in this process; available devices: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
```

I checked both CUDA and cuDNN:

```
nvcc -V
cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h
```

and got 8.0 and 5.1, respectively.

I call gpu like this:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
  a = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([100, 100]))
  b = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([100, 1000]))

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.matmul(a,b))
```

happy to post more details if necessary - don't know what will be useful yet.

Comment: possibly CUDA is not installed correctly.  What is the result of running `nvidia-smi` at a command prompt?

Comment: http://imgur.com/jTts2bp

Comment: Post the startup log of tensorflow.

Comment: http://imgur.com/5TyMraI

Comment: You need to install a NVIDIA Driver and run the CUDA 8.0 installer. You can find out how to do so here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422065/how-to-install-cuda-8-0-in-the-latest-version-of-tensorflow-1-0-in-aws-p2-xlar/

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're trying to set up an EC2 instance from scratch? That can be difficult.

Instead, I'd strongly recommend using the Deep Learning AMI (https://aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/amis/). It comes preinstalled with everything you need (drivers, popular DL libraries, etc.). It's also free to use, you just pay for the instance itself.